# How to send a JSON post request with RestTemplate without escaping double quotes?

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson, resttemplate, objectmapper

I am currently trying to send a request to an external API. I need to prepare a POST request with a JSON body containing a list of reports and send it with RestTemplate. This is my code:

```
//reportsJson is a list of Report objects containing some data
```

```java
 String postBody;
    try {
        postBody = objectMapper.copy()
        .setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)
        .writeValueAsString(reportsJson);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        log.error("Failed to serialize report.", e);
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
    
    var headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.setBearerAuth(getToken());
    
    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(postBody, headers);
    var response = restTemplate.exchange(API_URL, HttpMethod.POST, entity, ReportResponse.class);
```

Unfortunately, the response which I get from Server is HTTP 400 Bad Request:

```
'[{...},{...},{...}]' is not of type 'object'
```

EDIT:
I noticed that the problem is related to the escaping of double quotes in JSON within RestTemplate e.g:

```
{ \"id\" : { \"name\" : \"xyz\" } ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

The single quotes are not part of your json String; they are put there as part of rendering the error message.

Also, the error message is correct: your json is not an object, but an array (of object).

Examine the API specification of the service you are calling and see if the list is supposed to be tan attribute of a wrapper object, like:

```
{
    "data” : [<your objects>]
}
```

It is considered best practice for json payloads to be an object, not an array.

Comment: I was able to send a successful POST request using POSTMAN with exactly the same JSON, as an array

Comment: I mean the array directly, without wrapping it to the object with the attribute

Comment: @Peters_ print your payload to console, copy it and paste it into postman and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did. It works using postman

Comment: One logical explanation is you’re not calling the same URL from code as you are from postman

Comment: Unfortunately it is the same URL. It looks like the content type is not set right or something happens wrong in the last two lines of code. As mentioned copying postBody payload and sending it with postman works.

Comment: I think it is the similar issue like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52445749/how-to-avoid-string-escape-in-resttemplate-postforobject
but I am not sure how to send it as an array, because I cannot put List of objects to JSONObject